# How to reinstall android kitkat in HP Slate 7 voice tab using Mac

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, macos, hard-reset

My HP slate 7 voice tab is stuck with its logo when I try to switch it on. I also tried to hard reset it by holding all the three buttons (volume up + volume down + power) but it gets stuck on "product mode" with no further changes on the screen.

As I a noobie in this, any guidance is very much appreciated.

PS: As its an old tab, I am also fine with rooting it just to have it up and running for a few more years, rather than throwing it away. Kindly help

Comment: You can try if you get into recovery mode: https://droidrecovery.com/hp-slate-7-voicetab-recovery-mode/ If that doesn't work something is very wrong with your device and most likely the device or better it's flash memory has to be considered dead.